# Cassandra Container DB NoNodeAvailableException

Tags: docker, cassandra, docker-compose, datastax-java-driver

I use Cassandra docker image, spring boot services running on docker container, and use Datastax  Java driver.

I can connect connect Cassandra and also see logs, with the below docker compose file,

```
version: '3.5'

networks:
  my-network:

 cassandra-db:
    container_name: cassandra-db
    image: cassandra:4.0-beta1
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME='cassandra-cluster'
      - CASSANDRA_NUM_TOKENS=256
      - CASSANDRA_RPC_ADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch
    volumes:
      - ./out/cassandra_data:/var/lib/cassandra
    networks:
      - my-network


 client-service:
    container_name: client-service
    image: data/client-service
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
    ports:
      - 8087:8087
    depends_on:
      - cassandra-db
    links:
      - cassandra-db
    networks:
      - my-network
```

My keyspace query is,

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS SensorKeySpace WITH replication = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','replication_factor':3}
```

and building `Cqlsession` using,

```
.addContactEndPoint(new DefaultEndPoint(
                        InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved("cassandra-db",9042)))
                .withLocalDatacenter("DC1")
                .withKeyspace(CassandraConstant.KEY_SPACE_NAME.getValue())
                .build();
```

The Cassandra is up and running, and verified it,

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                  NAMES
57d1d29dbf00  client-service      "java -Djava.securit…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes   0.0.0.0:8087->8087/tcp                      client-service
00548a4058e6  cassandra:4.0-beta1  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago  Up 4 minutes   7000-7001/tcp, 7199/tcp, 9160/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9042->9042/tcp   cassandra-db
```

The problem was in the beginning,

1. I used `SimpleStrategy` to create Keyspace and got the below error,

```
Caused by: [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'session' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Since you provided explicit contact points, the local DC must be explicitly set (see basic.load-balancing-policy.local-datacenter in the config, or set it programmatically with SessionBuilder.withLocalDatacenter). Current contact points are: Node(endPoint=cassandra-db:9042, hostId=729bd04f-b345-4df3-a148-80545d30e032, hashCode=5563e4c4)=datacenter1. Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1
```

Then configured `.withLocalDatacenter("DC1")` and `- CASSANDRA_ENDPOINT_SNITCH=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` in docker compose.

2. After configuring, NO ERROR during startup the container but when i hit the query, i got the below error,

```
The Select Query is [SELECT NAME,VALUE FROM READING ]
client-service       | 2020-09-08 11:12:38.480 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8087-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraConnectionFailureException: Query; CQL [com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement@1265401a]; No node was available to execute the query; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query] with root cause
client-service       | com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException: No node was available to execute the query
```

I read the API doc, https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.0/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/NoNodeAvailableException.html which tell me

```
This can happen if all nodes are down, or if all the contact points provided at startup were invalid.
```

My Cassandra DB is up(verified), and connection is success to it. Anything is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

So the problem here, is the keyspace definition.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS SensorKeySpace WITH replication = 
    {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','replication_factor':3}
```

The `NetworkTopologyStrategy` is data center aware.  This means that it requires the replication to be set *per* data center.  From what I can see, it looks like your code is looking for the "DC1" data center.

```
.withLocalDatacenter("DC1")
```

But then, your logs are telling you:

> Current DCs in this cluster are: datacenter1

This means that your keyspace definition should look like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS SensorKeySpace WITH replication = 
    {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy','datacenter1':3}
```

And your code should be:

```
.withLocalDatacenter("datacenter1")
```

Note: Data center names are case-sensitive.  Be sure to verify the data center name you are using in the `cassandra-rackdc.properties` file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron, gonna try and keep you posted.